# Error: No model was found for relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model

```
Group = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue:"new group"}),

  founder: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true, inverse: 'groups'}),
  members: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true, inverse: 'group'}),
});
```

when I load it I respond from the server with

```
{
  "group":{
    "_id":"53ff8d82588266c710cf7a6c",
    "founder":"53fc31ac739be05911b94810",
    "members":[],
    "name":"new group"
    },
  "members":[]
 }
```

which results in an Error: No model was found for 'member'

I don't understand why it's trying to find a model called member, I specified that members is  a user relationship, so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the stack trace I found that the error started somewhere around line 3937: `var type = store.modelFor(typeName);`

I added a breakpoint and started tracing

I noticed that this piece of code iterated of the response singularizing in the previous line `'members'` to `'member'` as a model type.

I realized that ember-data is perhaps expecting a response that does not contain the relationship name but rather the model types to be loaded. so I changed the response to return users instead of members and it worked.

So apparently the response is supposed to contain the models not the relationships, which was misleading from the ember guide, since in the example the relationship was named after the model (comments in post)